# Abstract classes in client lib, and concrete class in shared lib

Tags: wcf, serialization, known-types

How do I solve the serialization problem with abstract class defined in a shared client library, and concrete implementation in a server side library.

```
Interface in shared client library :

  [ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
  [ServiceKnownType(typeof(SharedClient.Shape))]
  public interface IMyInterface
  {
    void UploadDrawing(Drawing dr);
  }

Concreate Drawing class in shared client library :

  [DataContract]
  [KnownType(typeof(SharedClient.Shape))]
  public class Drawing
  {
    public Shape s;
  }

Abstract class in shared client library :

  [DataContract]
  abstract public class Shape
  {
    [DataMember]
    public abstract string Name;
  }

Concrete class implementation in separate library which references the client library :

  [DataContract]
  public class Cirle : ClientLibrary.Shape
  {
    public override string Name { get; set; } 
  }
```

I keep getting the exception message:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:Drawing. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'Circle' with data contract name
>   'Circle:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/' is not expected.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known
>   statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known
>   types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException
>   for more details.

Comment: Please don't put things like "WCF - " in your titles. On [SO], tags serve the same purpose better.

Answer (score 1):

`KnownType` works in other way. If you want to use KnownType attribute you must use it on the base class to define its child:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Circle))]
abstract public class Shape
{
    [DataMember]
    public abstract string Name;
}
```

That will not be too much helpful in your case. Try to put ServiceKnownType with concrete class on your interface:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Circle))]
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void UploadDrawing(Drawing dr);
}
```

You doesn't have to define `Shape` as `ServiceKnownType` - it is already known because it is used in `Drawing` but WCF yet doesn't know the `Circle` type.

Comment: Ladislav, appreciate the reply. I cannot put concrete class Circle as a ServiceKnownType because it is defined in the library which has reference to the client library where the abstract class and interface is defined. There would be circular reference..

Comment: In such case you must redesign your libraries - service must know  types it uses.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you are right. Need to redesign. Surprisingly, the design works in .NET remoting.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this issue!!!. Did redesign the solution, and now I need to send a List<objects> part of my serialization. I have applied the attributes KnownType(typeof(List<object_type>)). Using DataContractSerializer, but it does not seem to serialize. Kindly help.